# writing submodules in different file in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-module

I am kind of stuck in the a middle of a personal project that I am doing. I have a scenario which is just not making any sense to me nor do I know what to "call it" so I am also not finding the right answers from internet.

If you can give a solution for me for the following example I would really appreciate it.

I am trying to do the following:

I have two classes/modules in different file(later maybe also adding inside sub directory as well).

**client.py**

```
class client(object):
    def __init__(self, user, key, address):
        self.user = user
        self.key = key
        self.address = address
```

**foo.py**

```
class foo(client):
    print(client.user, client.key, client.address)
```

Now I want to call foo() by initiating client() class first. So my test.py file should look like this and it should print those values I have given when initiating client class.

**test.py**

```
import client
f = client("x", "passkeyXX","10.192.0.1")
f.foo() ## should print the values given above
```

is this possible?

Comment: the init needs a self reference, have you checked if your import actually works? You might need to call it with client.py and a path to it depending on where you saved it

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do something similar to this --> [https://stackoverflow.com/q/46996982/7345804](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46996982/7345804)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this within one class, while not creating both:

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, user, key, address):
        self.user = user
        self.key = key
        self.address = address

    def foo(self):
        print(self.user, self.key, self.address)
```

Then you instantiate it in tests:

```
c = Client(user='user1', key='sdf234sdf13', address='USA, New York')
```

and call the needed method `foo`:

```
c.foo()
```

which should return you:

> user1 sdf234sdf13 USA, New York

**UPDATE:**

In `client.py`

```
from foo import foo as _f

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, user, key, address):
        self.user = user
        self.key = key
        self.address = address

    def foo(self):
        return _f(self.user, self.key, self.address)
```

In foo.py:

```
def foo(user, key, address):
   print(user, key, address)
```

Now you can import your class Client somewhere in tests.

```
from client import Client
```

Make instance:

```
c = Client(user='user1', key='sdf234sdf13', address='USA, New York')
```

call `c.foo()` and it should print out what you need, but this is so weird though

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am afraid I am not really looking for that. I can do what you have suggested by writing methods for the client class in the same file. But thats not what I want. I need to write the foo() in different file.

Comment: I need to make the class foo() subclass of client class but i need to make separate file for foo(). The reason I am asking is because I have several ( more then 50 classes) foo() like classes that would reside in my module directory.

Comment: You see, this, what you are talking about, is not subclassing and it's not logical. "foo" cannot be a class, but I can make this working like function of class Client and be called as "c.foo()". Do you want me to do this? Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Yes. I see the mistake. But the scenario still wont change. All I want is to have foo() in a separate file from the client.py and still be part of client() as a method or a subclass. If you can give me that kind of example it would be really really great! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To initialise a child class based on one of its parents, you can call the `super` method

Method 1: in the `__init__` method

```
class foo(client):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self, client).__init__(self, user, key, address)
```

Method 2: on specific object creation

```
bar = foo().super(self, client).__init__(<user>, <key>,< address>)
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) for details.